# HTTPClient Post & Request Default Value In Form

Tags: c#, post, request, httpclient

The form to be posted at the end auto generates a number (ID), that is auto filled, and I assume with a value that is not repeated. Without having access to the database, I am not sure how to properly add this to my post request so that the server will take it.

When I load the webpage front end, I see the grayed out ID field and it has a value. That being said I attempted this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = GetHtmlDocument(strContent);
string strTrying = (doc.GetElementbyId("IdOfElement").InnerText);
```

Essentially, the above is me creating an HTML document with the content string from a request to the page the form exists on. The reason I did this is because when I inspect the front end, with the DOM, I can see the value. I figured I could just pull it this way, then add to my post. However, when I print the content to see if its there, I see this:

```
        <td class="listItems">
        <input type="text" name="the_name" id="the_id" tabindex="2">
    </td>
```

No inner text is there against the id, but inspecting the front end, I can see it. If anyone has any insight on this that would be awesome. I think I am heading in the right direction, but not sure why the values of the items in the content I am pulling back in my request are not shown.

Also here is inspect the front end web page in the DOM:

```
  <INPUT tabIndex=2 id=the_id class=disabled readOnly maxLength=7 size=7 
   value=the_Value name=the_name>
```

Comment: I think some context is missing here. Are you reverse engineering a page and attempting to mimic its behavior to post a request? Does the page belong to your team or a third party?

Comment: 3rd party. I am trying to send a post request to a form on the page. Fiddler gave me the required fields I needed to send in my request, but the reason the server responds with an error, is because I cannot send the required field because I do not know what ID was going to be randomly generated during the process of filling out the form on the website. Does that clarify at all?

Answer (score 0):

The mysterious identifier is probably hard to spoof by design, and is likely to be a [CSRF token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) or some other security-related feature.

If you are lucky the identifier might be present in one of the cookies that came back with the page, but it is more likely that the cookie is encrypted and/or there is a copy of the identifier held on the server side, and if designed properly it will be impossible to guess.

If you are trying to spoof the behavior of the page when it is POSTed, you first need to spoof a request for the page when it is RENDERED initially. You can then read the identifier from the response, populate a request, and finally POST it.